# Command to check if there is any range versions in the dependencies section of the package.json

Tags: npm, package.json, semantic-versioning

Basically I want CI to fail if the dependencies section of the package.json contains any range operator. devDependencies could contain anything thought. Some CLI command would be perfect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Unfortunately, there is no existing built-in npm command/feature to achieve this. However, you  can utilize your own custom nodejs script. The nodejs script can then be invoked via a command if you define it in the `scripts` section of your *package.json*.

The following describes how to achieve this.

---

#### Solution

1. **`check-deps.js`**

   Create a nodejs script as follows. Let's name the script `check-deps.js` and save it somewhere in your project directory.

   ```js
   const isSemverRange = require('is-semver-range');

   const pkgPath = './path/to/your/package.json';
   const pkgData = require(pkgPath);

   function hasSemverRange({ dependencies = {}}) {
     return Object.values(dependencies).some(semver => isSemverRange(semver));
   }

   if (hasSemverRange(pkgData)) {
     console.log(`Semver range(s) found in dependencies section of ${pkgPath}`);
     process.exit(1);
   }
   ```

   **Explanation of `check-deps.js`:**

   - Firstly we `require` the [is-semver-range](https://github.com/tandrewnichols/is-semver-range) package, which we'll use to help check for any [semver ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#ranges). To install this package; `cd` to your project directory and run the following command:

     ```
     npm i -D is-semver-range
     ```
   - We then define a path to the *package.json* file (i.e. the file we want to check), and subsequently we `require` its contents.

     ```js
     const pkgPath = './path/to/your/package.json'; // <-- Redefine path.
     const pkgData = require(pkgPath);
     ```

     Note: you'll need to redefine your path to *package.json* as necessary.
   - The `hasSemverRange` function parameter definition utilizes [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to unpack the `dependencies` object, and assigns an empty object as a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) to avoid errors occurring if the `dependencies` section is missing from *package.json*.

     In the function body we pass in the `dependencies` object to the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method, and utilize the [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to test whether at least one of the values is a semver range.

     This function returns `true` if the value of any property/key of the `dependencies` object is as a semver range, otherwise it returns `false`.
   - Finally, in the `if` statement condition we invoke the `hasSemverRange` function, passing to it the parsed contents on *package.json*. If the condition is *truthy* we log an error message to the console, and exit the script with a non-zero exit code, i.e. `process.exit(1)`.
2. **package.json**

   In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* define a script as follows. Let's name the script `check-deps`:

   ```js
   "scripts": {
     "check-deps": "node path/to/check-deps.js",
     ...
   }
   ```

   Note: you'll need to redefine your path to *check-deps.js* as necessary.
3. **Running the npm script**

   Run the following command via your CLI to invoke the `check-deps` script:

   ```
   npm run check-deps
   ```

   If the value of any property defined in the `dependencies` section of your *package.json* is a semver range you'll see something like the following error logged to your console:

   > `Semver range(s) found in dependencies section of ./path/to/package.json`
4. **Integrating the check with your CI tool.**

   It's unclear from your question which CI tool you're using. However, typically CI tools provide a feature which allows you to invoke an npm script.

   For example, if your utilizing [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) you can define the script to run in your *.travis.yml* file as follows:

   **.travis.yml**

   ```
   script:
     - npm check-deps
   ```
5. **Additional Note:**

   You could also invoke the npm `check-deps` script via an existing `test` script which you may have already defined in your *package.json* by utilizing the `&&` operator. For instance:

   ```js
   "scripts": {
     "check-deps": "node path/to/check-deps.js",
     "test": "yourCurrentTestcommands && npm run check-deps"
     ...
   }
   ```

   Note: In the `test` script above the `yourCurrentTestcommands` part should be replaced with any commands that you may currently be running.

---